# Tabbar icons display incorrect

Tags: ios, iphone, tabbar

In  my App there is a Tabbar with four tabs. I add the tabbar icon resources (50x50) into the `Images.xcassets`. But I found that one of the icosn displayed incorrect as the following image:

[image: tab bar image]

```
- (void)customTabBarItems{
    self.tabBar.superview.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    NSArray *items = self.tabBar.items;
    NSArray *normalImgs = @[@"tab_home_normal",@"tab_message_normal",@"tab_order_normal",@"tab_userCenter_normal"];
    NSArray *selectedImgs = @[@"tab_home_selected",@"tab_message_selected",@"tab_order_selected",@"tab_userCenter_selected"];

    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < items.count; i++) {
        UITabBarItem *item = [items objectAtIndex:i];
        NSString *title = titleArr[i];
        UIImage *normalImg = [UIImage imageNamed:normalImgs[i]];
        UIImage *selectImg = [UIImage imageNamed:selectedImgs[i]];
        item.title = title;
        if (isIOS7Later) {
            item.image = normalImg;
            item.selectedImage = selectImg;
        }
        else{
            [item setFinishedSelectedImage:selectImg withFinishedUnselectedImage:normalImg];
        }
    }
}

//set tint color 

- (void)_customAppearance
{
    if (isIOS7Later)
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent animated:NO];
    }

    UIColor * color = [UIColor whiteColor];
    NSDictionary * dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:color forKey:UITextAttributeTextColor];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:dict];

    if (isIOS7Later)
    {
        [[UITabBar appearance] setTintColor:BGCOLOR(21.0, 170.0, 255.0, 1.0)];
    }
    else
    {
        NSDictionary *textAttributesNormal = @{UITextAttributeTextColor: BGCOLOR(179, 179, 179, 1)};
        NSDictionary *textAttributesSelected = @{UITextAttributeTextColor:BGCOLOR(0, 154, 255, 1)};
        [[UITabBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tab_select_image"]];
        [[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:textAttributesNormal forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:textAttributesSelected forState:UIControlStateSelected];
        [[UITabBar appearance] setSelectedImageTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        [[UITabBar appearance] setSelectionIndicatorImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tab_select_image"]];
    }

    [SVProgressHUD setForegroundColor:BGCOLOR(0, 135.0, 231, 1)];
    [SVProgressHUD setDefaultMaskType:SVProgressHUDMaskTypeBlack];
}

//Images.xcassets
```

When I changed the first icon to another, it seems ok, but I want to use  this one:

[image: tab image]

Comment: As a note for future posts: Format your code properly. People will react better if you do so.

Comment: @steven try to post question correctly...

Comment: Is the "HUI" white part transparent or actually white ?

Comment: @Quentin Hayot  That part is transparent.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the problem is in tint color. Tint color changes image visible pixels color, so it usually uses for changing color of images with transparency. Seems like your image have no transparent background, so tint color makes it whole blue. Please, check your image source. One more possible solution if your image is good - use rendering mode for image before setting it:

```
UIImage *toSet = [yourImage  imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate];
```

Comment: Thanks, I change the render mode to Template Image  in Image set, but it doesn't work. And the background of the  image is transparent.

Answer (score 0):

The more recent answer is to change the rendering mode of your icons to original image:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/38560183/3885491

Answer (score -1):

Must change the rendering mode of your icons to original image

[image]