# How to set Image in Tabbar not Tint color in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, uistoryboard, uitabbar

I have an application with `UITabbar` , I want to set image in Tabbar but am unable to set image in Tabbar. Instead of as it is image i get image shape in tint color, Is it possible to set image as it is in Tabbar? .

i have Tried this code but Unable to set image.

```
UITabBar *tabBar = self.tabBar;

UITabBarItem *targetTabBarItem = [[tabbar items] objectAtIndex:0]; // whichever tab-item
UIImage *selectedIcon = [UIImage imageNamed:@"name-of-selected-image.png"];
[targetTabBarItem setSelectedImage:selectedIcon];
```

Comment: add image through attribute inspector

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You need to set your image attributes property `Render As` to `Original Image`. To change this select your image from assets and in the `Attributes Inspector` set `Render As` property to `Original Image` like this.

[image]

Comment: But image tint colour is not changing ?

Comment: @kishor0011 Yes, after setting rander mode to original image you can not use tint color with that image.

Answer (score 0):

Select your TabBar Item and set your image like this

[image]

**OR**

Set selected tint color try this

```
[[UITabBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

    [UITabBarItem.appearance setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor whiteColor]} forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [[UITabBar appearance] setSelectionIndicatorImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"name-of-selected-image.png"]];
    [[UITabBar appearance]setSelectedItem:[[UITabBar appearance].items objectAtIndex:2]];
```