# How to set image in a tab bar item in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I have taken a view controller & embedded it in a navigation Controller and again this has been embedded in a tab bar controller. when I am trying to set a image via story board, the image does not appear on a tab bar icon. Here image name is 25.

[image]

[image]

What can I do? How can I do it programmatically? what should I take proper image size for this purpose?

Comment: NO, no need to do it prog.. It can be done via above method too.

Comment: But why this is not working on my project?

Comment: Can you show the output screenshot.

Comment: this is looking like the last image

Comment: May be this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/38560183/6433023

Comment: Use transparent image for Tab bar

Answer (score 22):

**In your MainTabbarViewController**

*Bind the outlet of your tabbar:*

```
@IBOutlet weak var myTabBar: UITabBar?
 
 override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      
      myTabBar?.tintColor = UIColor.white
      tabBarItem.title = ""
      
      setTabBarItems()
      
 }
```

set the tabbar items here defined method below:

```
func setTabBarItems(){
      
      let myTabBarItem1 = (self.tabBar.items?[0])! as UITabBarItem
      myTabBarItem1.image = UIImage(named: "Unselected")?.withRenderingMode(UIImage.RenderingMode.alwaysOriginal)
      myTabBarItem1.selectedImage = UIImage(named: "Selected ")?.withRenderingMode(UIImage.RenderingMode.alwaysOriginal)
      myTabBarItem1.title = ""
      myTabBarItem1.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 6, left: 0, bottom: -6, right: 0)
      
      let myTabBarItem2 = (self.tabBar.items?[1])! as UITabBarItem
      myTabBarItem2.image = UIImage(named: "Unselected")?.withRenderingMode(UIImage.RenderingMode.alwaysOriginal)
      myTabBarItem2.selectedImage = UIImage(named: "Selected")?.withRenderingMode(UIImage.RenderingMode.alwaysOriginal)
      myTabBarItem2.title = ""
      myTabBarItem2.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 6, left: 0, bottom: -6, right: 0)
      
      
      let myTabBarItem3 = (self.tabBar.items?[2])! as UITabBarItem
      myTabBarItem3.image = UIImage(named: "Unselected")?.withRenderingMode(UIImage.RenderingMode.alwaysOriginal)
      myTabBarItem3.selectedImage = UIImage(named: "Selected")?.withRenderingMode(UIImage.RenderingMode.alwaysOriginal)
      myTabBarItem3.title = ""
      myTabBarItem3.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 6, left: 0, bottom: -6, right: 0)
      
      let myTabBarItem4 = (self.tabBar.items?[3])! as UITabBarItem
      myTabBarItem4.image = UIImage(named: "Unselected")?.withRenderingMode(UIImage.RenderingMode.alwaysOriginal)
      myTabBarItem4.selectedImage = UIImage(named: "Selected")?.withRenderingMode(UIImage.RenderingMode.alwaysOriginal)
      myTabBarItem4.title = ""
      myTabBarItem4.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 6, left: 0, bottom: -6, right: 0)
      
 }
```

Comment: what is the use of tab bar outlet if you are not using it anywhere?

Answer (score 14):

add AppDelegate class :

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool
{
    window=UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    self.window?.rootViewController = setTabbar()
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    window?.backgroundColor=UIColor.white
    return true
}

func setTabbar() -> UITabBarController
{
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let tabbarcntrl = UITabBarController()

    let Home = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeView") // 1st tab bar viewcontroller
    let Followed = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FollowedView") // 2nd tab bar viewcontroller
    let Message = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MessageView") // 3rd tab bar viewcontroller

    // all viewcontroller embedded navigationbar
    let nvHome = UINavigationController(rootViewController: Home)
    let nvFollowed = UINavigationController(rootViewController: Followed)
    let nvMessage = UINavigationController(rootViewController: Message)

    // all viewcontroller navigationbar hidden
    nvHome.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)
    nvFollowed.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)
    nvMessage.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)

    tabbarcntrl.viewControllers = [nvHome,nvFollowed,nvMessage]

    let tabbar = tabbarcntrl.tabBar
    tabbar.barTintColor = UIColor.black
    tabbar.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    tabbar.tintColor = UIColor(red: 43/255, green: 180/255, blue: 0/255, alpha: 1)

    //UITabBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.white
    let attributes = [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont(name: "Montserrat-Light", size: 10)!,NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.white]
    let attributes1 = [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont(name: "Montserrat-Light", size: 10)!,NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor(red: 43/255, green: 180/255, blue: 0/255, alpha: 1)]

    UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes(attributes, for: .normal)
    UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes(attributes1, for: .selected)


    let tabHome = tabbar.items![0]
    tabHome.title = "Home" // tabbar titlee
    tabHome.image=UIImage(named: "icon_home.png")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal) // deselect image
    tabHome.selectedImage = UIImage(named: "icon_home.png")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal) // select image
    tabHome.titlePositionAdjustment.vertical = tabHome.titlePositionAdjustment.vertical-4 // title position change

    let tabFoll = tabbar.items![1]
    tabFoll.title = "Followed"
    tabFoll.image=UIImage(named: "icon_fold.png")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
    tabFoll.selectedImage=UIImage(named: "icon_fold.png")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
    tabFoll.titlePositionAdjustment.vertical = tabFoll.titlePositionAdjustment.vertical-4

    let tabMsg = tabbar.items![3]
    tabMsg.title = "Message"
    tabMsg.image=UIImage(named: "icon_mail.png")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
    tabMsg.selectedImage=UIImage(named: "icon_mail.png")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
    tabMsg.titlePositionAdjustment.vertical = tabMsg.titlePositionAdjustment.vertical-4

    return tabbarcntrl
}
```

Comment: in AppDelegate class

Answer (score 7):

**Set both images- for select/selected state**

[image: See This]

Comment: I did like you but same problem. Is it a bug or problem of my computer I could not understand. Is their any naming convention of image,image size?

Comment: when I am using icon from iconbeast or icons8 they are finely displayed but when I am using my image they are not supported. Any idea?

Comment: [See This](https://github.com/mho000/MHImageTabBar) and check what was error in your code

Answer (score 7):

You are doing all the things in right way But the only problem is your tabbaritem image is not in correct size .Just look this table for actual size of tabbaritem images.

[image]

Comment: when i downloaded image from image icon,its property shows 30x30

Comment: You need to create 1x , 2x , 3x of Tabbar icon.So Proper assets for your image are :  30x30 - 1x, 60x60 - 2x,90x90 - 3x

Comment: what does  (About 75 x 75) means?

Comment: it's an example size only if you have 1x image of size 25x25 then you have 75x75 in 3x .

Answer (score 0):

In swift 4 and 5 you can use the below extension. Remember one thing always pass the same number of images , selected images and title but if you do not want to set title then pass nil in title.

```swift
extension UITabBarController{        
        func setUpImagaOntabbar(_ selectedImage : [UIImage], _ image : [UIImage], _ title : [String]?){
            
            for (index,vals) in image.enumerated(){
                
                if let tab = self.tabBar.items?[index]{
                    
                    tab.image = image[index]
                    tab.image = selectedImage[index]
                    if let tile = title[index]{
                       tab.title = title[index]
                      }
                    
                }
            }
        }
    }
```