# Is it possible to draw online image on tab bar item?

Tags: ios, image, tabbar, react-native-navigation

I want to put online image on tab bar item.

Is this possible in iOS?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use **WebImage** and load it by using **SDWebImage**.

https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage

So once it load and you get the object of `UIImage` inside its method you can check UIImage object should not be nil If not nil then set that `UIImage` to your tabbar Item Image.

```
imageView.sd_setImageWithURL(NSURL(string: urlString), completed: {
            (image, error, cacheType, url) in
            // Change tabbar item image here....

           tabHome.image=image?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal) // deselect image
           tabHome.selectedImage = image?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal) // select image


        })
```

Reference:  [how to set image in a tab bar item in swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39715932/how-to-set-image-in-a-tab-bar-item-in-swift/39716048)

Comment: Thanks Man. This Question and Answer both helped me in an unexpected way. Sometimes, It only requires a line or two to enlighten the code. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is possible in iOS via `UITabBarItem`
You need to select UITabBarItem constructor for your business and **set the image**

```
UITabBarItem(title: String?, image: UIImage?, selectedImage: UIImage?)
UITabBarItem(title: String?, image: UIImage?, tag: Int)
```