# UITabBar items with each one different color when selected

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbaritem

I have a multiple page tab bar application. I want each tab bar item (image) to have its own color when selected. For example, the first one should be red when selected, the second should be blue, the third should be yellow... 
I have tried to use this in my app delegate but it changes the color of all the selected images to the same color:

```
            UITabBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor(red: 6/255, green: 162/255, blue: 198/255, alpha: 1)
```

I want each one to be different than the other when selected. I'm using swift 3.0. Any help please?
Thanks.

Comment: For that you need to set the selected image property with your selected image.

Comment: I've already put a selected image with different color for each one. But it's not showing any color when selected...

Comment: Check this one http://stackoverflow.com/a/38560183/6433023 and no need to set tintColor of tabbar.

Comment: Thanks, it worked!

Comment: Welcome mate :)

Comment: Please, check my detailed answer on: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43002013/different-colors-for-tabbar-items-in-tab-bar-controller/47644313#47644313

Answer (score 2):

Add this line for every tab:

```
 tabBar.items![0].setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor(red: 1/255.0, green: 185/255.0, blue: 224/255.0, alpha: 1.0)], for: UIControlState.selected)
```