# Tabbar item images not loaded first time

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

i am using tabbarcontroller in my project. Here is my storyboard

[image]

In all view controllers tabbar item, I set images like below

[image]

I make a class of tabbarcontroller and do coding below

```
    UITabBar *tabBar = self.tabBar;
    UITabBarItem *tabBarItem1 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0];
    UITabBarItem *tabBarItem2 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:1];
    UITabBarItem *tabBarItem3 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:2];
    UITabBarItem *tabBarItem4 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:3];
    UITabBarItem *tabBarItem5 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:4];

//    [tabBarItem1 setImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"ic_home_tab_home_sel"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal]];
//    [tabBarItem1 setSelectedImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"ic_home_tab_home_sel"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal]];




    [tabBarItem1 setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ic_home_tab_home_sel"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ic_home_tab_home"]];
    [tabBarItem2 setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ic_home_tab_profile_sel"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ic_home_tab_profile"]];
    [tabBarItem3 setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ic_home_create_post_sel"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ic_home_create_post"]];
    [tabBarItem4 setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ic_home_tab_chat_sel"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ic_home_tab_chat"]];
    [tabBarItem5 setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ic_home_tab_setting_sel"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ic_home_tab_setting"]];
```

But When I run it, [image]
First time all images are mixed, But when I clicked them one by one like in [Video](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wrbz37lnvg55jap/v1.mov?dl=0) then all images sets.
I dont know why this happend? 
Please help me
Thank you

Comment: So, You mean like I set images 2 times and I have to delete my code ?? Right @NiravD

Comment: What i'm saying is you have already set image for selected bar item also so Yes, there is no need to add that code.

Comment: but when I comment code and try ,same issue came

Comment: My comment is not related to your question i'm just suggesting that there is no need to set image 2 times here.

Comment: ok , @NiravD I understand but how can I solve this problem ./

Comment: Have you added any other code ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136242/discussion-between-jecky-modi-and-nirav-d).

Comment: I am running ios 10 using iphone SE simulator with Xcode 8.0 Nirav D

Comment: I have checked it with same simulator doesn't face issue you are talking about also you need to made some changes for your tabbar item image

Comment: @NiravD you mean my project works completely without any change ? It may xcode 8.0 problem ?

Comment: I have also check it in Xcode 8, Also you need to make little bit changes because you haven't properly set image for all tabbar item.

Comment: So where I make change you're talking about ?

Comment: Select your tabbar items and set proper image for both selected and image property of tabbaritem because in some place you are setting selected for both image, Also set your image rendering mode as original image check this answer of my for that http://stackoverflow.com/a/38560183/6433023

Comment: ok, Thanks I will check it

Comment: Check this image for how to set render mode to original image https://i.stack.imgur.com/EnVOK.png

Comment: Yeah, I got it. Thanks buddy.

Comment: Is it working now? After setting this one.

Comment: @NiravD It's working completely. Thanks

Comment: Welcome mate :) Glad it works for you :)

Answer (score 0):

I also faced same problem then I used below code in `appdelegate`

```
 UINavigationController *navigationVC1 = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:viewController1];
    navigationVC1.tabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"My Trips"
                                                             image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cab.png"]
                                                               tag:1];

    UINavigationController *navigationVC2 = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:viewController2];
    navigationVC2.tabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"My Children"
                                                             image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"kids-couple.png"]
                                                               tag:2];
```

try like this.